# Eclipse maven project package disorder

Tags: eclipse, maven

Maven project is usually organized as src/main/java/somepackage, but from time to time my eclipse would recognize src/main/java as part of package too. How to fix this?
In the following picture, common and helloworld are both maven projects, where common is organized correctly but helloworld is not.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `src` directory is the **default** directory where Eclipse stores the source code, while in Maven is `src/main/java`. Better check if the `.classpath` file has not been corrupted or externally modified. It should contain something like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
```

Comment: that is awesome. Just one thing, I had always thought .class file should not be altered manually, should have some entry in eclipse, like project properties or window preferences.

Comment: You are right: The .classpath file should not be edited manually. Its contents must be edited visually through the project's `Java Build Path/sources` window. But there is a chance that the file gets corrupted or overried externally (maybe downloading it accidentally from a Source Control System).

Answer (score 0):

The code line
`package main.java.helloworld;`
in the helloworld project results in this **package** hierarchy:

```
main
`-+ java
  `-+ helloworld
```

Is that really what you mean?
In a maven project, you have this directory structure:

```
src
`-+ main
|   `-+ java
|   |   `-+ <here your packages and classes>
|   '-+ resources
|
'-+ test
|   `-+ java
|   |   `-+ <here your test packages and classes>
|   '-+ resources
```

`src/main/java` (production code) and `src/test/java` (tests only) are the root of your package hierarchy. If you create the nested packages `com.enterprise` within `test/java` and create a class `Test` within `enterprise`, then you have to insert this package declaration in `Test.java`:
`package com.enterprise;`

Take a look at your directory and package structure in the helloworld project.

Comment: I have that maven default folder hierarchy, src/main/java/helloworld/Foo.java and helloworld is the package. But when import this maven project into eclipse, sometimes (not always) it treats this  src/main/java as part of package, this time (helloworld shown in the pic) eclipse treats main/java/helloworld as the package, and asks me to change package helloworld to package main.java.helloworld.

Comment: look at the second screenshot in your question. You wrote `package main.java.helloworld;` . That means that you declare `main`, `java` and `helloworld` as packages. This is confusing for eclipse and wrong, because `main` and `java` belong to the maven folder structure.

Comment: That is eclipse autofix. It was import helloworld; and with an error: The declared package "helloworld" does not match the expected package "main.java.helloworld"

Comment: open the File Explorer and look how the directory structure is organized. My proposal: make a backup of your Java files (with correct package structure), POM.xml and delete the eclipse project from disk. Then create a new eclipse project.

Comment: The first picture is taken from project explorer. I have tried reimport. I would think that there could be a configuration somewhere indicating the package in eclipse project properties. just couldn't find it.

Comment: I can't give you more advice. Perhaps you selected the wrong directory when you imported the maven project to eclipse.